# Giving land to developers who work there by money from interest based loan

Tags: riba

We know that after giving our land to them to work with the developers are going to take loan from conventional bank (involving RIBA) to work on my piece of land. So my question is, is it halal to give the land to the developers knowing they are doing it by loan based money?